# createdb: permission denied to create database

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, heroku

I'm trying to set up a Heroku environment for python development following instructions on https://github.com/heroku/python-getting-started. When I run `createdb python_getting_started`:

- I'm first prompted to give in a password: I entered the password of the user "postgres" in Postgres
- I get an error message:

  > createdb database creation failed: ERROR: permission denied to create database

Don't really how to solve this one. The user "postgres" is allowed to create a database. I checked with `\du` that it is a Superuser and it has Create DB rights. What's going on here? Which user is Windows using to try to create a Postgres DB?

Answer (score 0):

Most PostgreSQL utilities by default use your current OS session login for database connections.

You need to either set environment variable `PGUSER` to postgres or use `createdb -U postgres python_getting_started`.

You can read more about `createdb` parameters [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-createdb.html), tho admittedly it does not mention default values.

EDIT: It actually does mention that it uses libpq defaults, and those [are](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNECT-USER):

> *user*
>   PostgreSQL user name to connect as. Defaults to be the same as the operating system name of the user running the application.